# how to auto-wire int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter?

Tags: spring-integration

I need to gracefully turn off spring integration app. before calling applicationContext.close() i want to stop to listen the messages. Please let me know how to auto wire message-driven-channel-adapter?

Answer (score 2):

An underlaying component of the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` is `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint`. And if you declare an `id` on that component you can inject that object by that class and `@Qualifier` with that `id`.

From other side there is no reason to `stop` it manually: `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` implements `SmartLifecycle`, hence its `stop()` is called from the `applicationContext.close()` phase properly.

Comment: I have another question, for ex if my JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint drops 1000 msgs are in executor queue and service activator is processing each msg one after one. in the mean time if i call applicationContext.close(), does integration guarantees to process all by service activator

Comment: For that purpose you should configure your `TaskExecutor` with `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown = true` and some `awaitTerminationSeconds` timeout.

Comment: thanks for prompt response Artem..I will add your suggestions

Comment: I would __STRONGLY__ suggest that it is better to use the concurrency settings on the `message-driven-channel-adapter` for concurrency rather than using executor channels for this application. That way, you can rely on the container for recovery (if you use `acknowledge="transacted"` or a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with `acknowledge="auto"). Even with @ArtemBilan 's suggestion you could lose messages if you lose power.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have updated message driven adapter as below and converted executor channel to direct channel.

 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="cme_cbt" destination="requestQueue"  channel="jmsInChannel" 
    transaction-manager="txManager" acknowledge="auto" concurrent-consumers="3"/>